# Delay when using `mv` command

Tags: bash, mv

I have a directory with many files. If I move a file to a subdirectory by `mv myfile.* ./subdirectory/`, I have a delay of about 3 seconds. Then the files are moved.

How can I avoid this delay?

---

The background is, that I want to sort this directory. So I have written a script to check the content of a configuration file and move the configuration file plus 2 other files to a special subdirectory.

Comment: Are you saying there's a delay first where nothing happens, and then the files get moved all at once? That would sound a bit surprising, as pretty much the only thing that happens beforehand is the shell fetching the list of filenames to pass to `mv`. The moves themselves would necessarily happen one-by-one.

Comment: How many files are "many"?

Comment: Is this on a local filesystem or a remotely mounted one?

Comment: `*` will read all possible files, and bash will also sort the files. You may want to use `find` which can batch operations before getting whole content of the directory

Comment: @Kusalananda - many are... ?? I can't use `ls` to count because there are too many. (usually I use `ls -1 | wc -l` to get the number of files)

Comment: @ChrisDavies - I looked up the "/proc/mounts" file. But there's no entry to that directory. So I think it's not mounted.

Comment: @ilkkachu - I enter the `mv ...` command, then I have to wait and then there is an output, that 3 files are renamed. (Maybe there is a delay of the output)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi - I tried `find . -name "foo.*"`. I had in mind to add an `-execute`. But it's not faster. - So I tried simply `ls foo.*`: Then I have a delay. `ls foo.pdf` theres no delay. - But I can't use 3 mount commands because I don't know if there is always a pdf file or maybe there are files I don't know...

Comment: `find -maxdepth 1 -printf . | wc -c` should give you the number of files/directories +1

Comment: `find -maxdepth 1 -printf . | wc -c` will give you one more than the number of files/directories. And `find -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf . | wc -c` will give you the precise number of files (without directories)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have hundreds of thousands of files or more, then the time you see is the time it takes your shell to identify all possible expansions of the glob `myfile.*`. That means it looks for all file names starting with `myfile.` and then any number of any other character.  So when you have very many files, that means very many files to check and some lag.

To avoid the lag, use the actual file name: `mv myfile.whatever ./subdirectory/`. If that isn't an option, and you need to find the file names on the fly, then either start using more subdirectories so none of your directories has too many files, or just learn to live with the wait.

Comment: Maybe it's better to leave this alone. It was just an idea to handle an chaos (thats not really mine). But thank you though!